# runOutput isn't appearing even after using dbutils.notebook.exit in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am using the below code to get some information in the Azure Databricks notebook, but runOutput isn't appearing even after the successful completion of the notebook activity.

Code that I used.

```
import json
dbutils.notebook.exit(json.dumps({
    "num_records" : dest_count,
    "source_table_name" : table_name
}))
```

Databricks notebook exited properly, but Notebook activity isn't showing runOutput.

Can someone please help me what is wrong here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is working fine for me when I tried with Existing cluster in my environment. https://i.imgur.com/8bek0HS.png. Try to store it in a String variable in ADF using `@string(activity('Notebook1').output.runOutput)` and see if you are able to get it.

Comment: Yes, it suppose to come, but for some reason, runOuput isn't coming to me. @RakeshGovindula. But, not to block my work, I found an alternate way to get this.

Comment: Consider posting your alternative way as answer for other community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why it is not populating runOuput. Basically, I need to get number of records it is pushing to Azure Synapse, So I have used Lookup Activity to get the Number of records in that table.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried the above in my environment, it is working fine for me.

These are my Linked service Configurations.

[image]

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

I suggest you try the troubleshooting steps like, changing Notebook and changing the Databricks workspace with new one or using Existing cluster in linked service.

If still, it is giving the same, then it's better to raise a [Support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) for your issue.